# How to write the correct syntax for this question?

Tags: r, machine-learning

A dataset named "rain" contains information on raining in four different countries. How to create a subset of the data that only contain raining information when "country" is 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To subset your dataset, assuming it is a dataframe, you can use

`rain1 <- rain[rain$country == 1, ]`

Programming questions are better suited to [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) by the way.